# Set cumulative value when faced with overflowing Int16

Tags: mysql, overflow, bit-manipulation

I have cumulative input values that start life as smallints.
I read these values from a Access database, and aggregate them into a MySQL database.

Now I'm faced with input values of type smallint that are cumulative, thus always increasing.

```
Input            Required output
---------------------------------
0                0
10000            10000
32000            32000
-31536           34000             //overflow in the input
-11536           54000
8464             74000
```

I process these values by inserting the raw data into a blackhole table and in the trigger to the blackhole I upgrade the data before inserting it into the actual table.

I know how to store the previous input and output, or if there is none, how to select the latest (and highest) inserted value.
But what's the easiest/fastest way to deal with the overflow, so I get the correct output.

Answer (score -1):

Given you have a table named `test` with a primary key called `id` and the column is named `value` Then just do this:

```
SELECT
  id,
  test.value,
  (SELECT SUM(value) FROM test AS a WHERE a.id <= test.id) as output
FROM test;
```

This would be the output:

```
------------------------
| id | value  | output |
------------------------
|  1 |  10000 |  10000 |
|  2 |  32000 |  42000 |
|  3 | -31536 |  10464 |
|  4 | -11536 |  -1072 |
|  5 |  8464  |   7392 |
------------------------
```

Hope this helps.

If it doesn't work, just convert your data to `INT` (or `BIGINT` for lots of data). It does not hurt and memory is cheap this days.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt, I understand the idea, but the output does not match that required in the question. I think you misunderstood my intention.